# Replace Javascript method malfunction

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm facing some mysterious problem in my web development : I'm trying to replace the UTF-8 2 bytes characters by their console equivalent,
because when I put a string downloaded from a UTF-8 file, the extended characters appear as 2 characters, for example "é" has become "Ã©".
So I wrote a function to replace those 2 bytes sequences by the original character.

The problem is that, very curiously, the Javascript "replace" method seems failing to replace some of those sequences: in the first "paragraph" of the extended range (paragraph 128-143 or 80h-8Fh), 13 characters are correctly replaced, but 3 of them are not. And that looks incomprehensible to me.

So here's a code sample of 2 characters having to be replaced by "Ç" and "é". Since it didn't work with "Ç", I replaced it by "Z" which is an ordinary character, in case "Ç" itself would have been the cause of the malfunction.

So here is the code:

```
   var str = "AÃ‡Ã©B"
    var lg = str.length;
    var b16 = U.enBase16(str); // the enBase16 function converts a string to the hesadecimal expression of its bytes
    var tx = str;
    tx = tx.replace(/\xC3\x87/g,"Z");
    tx = tx.replace(/\xC3\xA9/g,"é");
```

the "b16" string is there to check there is no hidden byte inside the string, and also to check that "Ã‡" is with no doubt the hex word "C387"

And here is the result displayed in my page :

```
str = AÃ‡Ã©B, length =6
b16 = 41c387c3a942
tx = AÃ‡éB
```

So, there you can see that "é" has been correctly restored, but "Z" did not appear, and the original sequence "Ã‡" has remained.
Can someone tell me why Javascript refuses to replace the sequence \xC3\x87 ?

Comment: Have you tried `"mybrokenstr".normalize("NFC")`?

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem. you need to fix the source or read the data using the correct codepage

Comment: The XY problem will probably be true, but sometimes that's the data you get with no hopes of changing it

Comment: Could someone please try that code to confirm it's not a bizarre problem in my own machine ?

Comment: Sorry Vivick, I d'ont see what a "X/Y problem" can be ?

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Well, my html page is delared as UTF-8.

Comment: I've tried .normalize("NFC", but the string remains the same.

Comment: Well, this is just what my HTML page does: it doesn't interpret "C387" as unicode for "Ç", but takes it as 2 separate 1 byte characters:  "Ã" and "‡"

Comment: Here's what I could reproduce: Character 0x87 is not defined in any ISO 8859 character set. If it appears in an HTML page that claims to be ISO-8859-1, for example, the browser displays it as a double dagger "‡" or [U+2021](https://compart.com/en/unicode/U+2021#characters), a character that does not exist in ISO 8859.

Comment: Thank you Heiko for that useful answer, which is a valuable explanation of the problem. So I'll have to find another way to work it out.

Comment: @BBBreiz What exactly are you doing with the downloaded UTF-8 data (and how are you downloading it)? Please show us that code. You only mention a "*console"* and that you "*put a string*" and that you want a "*result displayed in my page*", but it's not clear at all. Without more details about your program and its environment, we cannot tell where those encoding problems come from or how to fix them - all we can say is that `.replace()` is certainly the wrong approach.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the answer was finally very simple:
the sequence

```
tx = tx.replace(/\xC3\x87/g,"Ç");
```

definitely doesn't work, and it is quite strange, because the following one works perfectly well :

```
tx = tx.replace(/Ã‡/g,"Ç");
```

Comment: Note that alongside using a regex with a global flag, you can alternatively use the `replaceAll()` method: `tx = tx.replaceAll('Ã‡', 'Ç');`